# If input = "whatever", then show element and if not, show a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to do this for about an hour now looking up codes but I just can't find out how to do this.

I need a kind of ask answer thing.
Lets say its like a quick math quiz and the question is "what's 2 plus 2?" and if the answer with 4, then a div would show after they click the button.

But if they answer with anything else, than a different element would show.
Here's what I have so far,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button#try").click(function(){
    if(!$('input#input1').val() = "4"){
      $('#yeselement').show();
    }

    else {
      $('#noelement').show();
    }
  });
});
```

but for me, it doesn't work. Is something wrong with the code? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `!=` to compare:

```
if ( $('input#input1').val() != "4") {
//                            ^ you want to compare, not assign
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` for comparisons. You also need a pair of parenthesis for grouping:

```
if ( !($('input#input1').val() == "4") )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `!==` or `===` in your condition:

```
if($('input#input1').val() !== "4") {
```

Note that `==` and `!=` also work but are less safe than `===` and `!==`.

Source: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)